# Mentioning people with multi-word display names or user ids in a Slack Message using a WebHook and Ansible Slack

Tags: ansible, webhooks, slack-api

I'm using the Ansible `slack` module to send notifications, which include @mentions for notifiable people. I'm having trouble with multi-word display names, though single-word display names work fine.

For example:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "message: `SANDPIT` started ELMS and LACM MapGuide\nFYI <@alice> <@bob>"
}
```

But then `<@Genghis Khan>` comes to work alongside Alice and Bob. And he, because he's Ghengis Khan, of course chooses a multi-word display name. Given the following message:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "message: `SANDPIT` started ELMS and LACM MapGuide\nFYI <@Ghenkis Khan> <@bob>"
}
```

`@bob` is recognised, `<@Ghenkis Khan>` isn't.

I've also tried user ids as recommended at https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-the-one-about-usernames but they don't work any better, so I've reverted to display names. But for completeness here is an example of the message content, with valid user ids but an invalid result:

```
TASK [slack : debug] 
***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "message: `SANDPIT` started ELMS and LACM MapGuide\nFYI <@U12345DK> <@U12345TT>"
}
```

As mentioned, Slack is not buying these user ids either.

Here's the Ansible task that sends the message to Slack. All tokens etc are working as expected, and this is all happening in the same workspace.

```
- name: Send message via Slack
  slack:
    token: 'valid token'
    color: 'valid color'
    msg: '{{ message }}'
    link_names: 1
  # problems with notifications should not fail the pipeline
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Comment: As mentioned in the Slack memo linking usernames is no longer recommended and will stop working completely in September 2017. So you want to focus on making your app work with user IDs, which btw. usually works great.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/slack_module.html) of the msg property of the slack plugin all angle brackets and ampersands need to be escaped using HTML notation:

> Message to send. Note that the module does not handle escaping
>   characters. Plain-text angle brackets and ampersands should be
>   converted to HTML entities (e.g. & to &) before sending. See
>   Slack's documentation (https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting)
>   for more.

So you want to try something like this:

```
TASK [slack : debug] 
***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "message: `SANDPIT` started ELMS and LACM MapGuide\nFYI &lt;@U12345DK&gt; &lt;@U12345TT&gt;"
}
```

Comment: I don't want to escape the angle brackets because when you escape them they don't do their job-- they become literal text output by Slack.Here, they are special characters used to identify @mentions. When I escape them I get `FYI &lt;@U830369DK&gt; &lt;@U6M9NQD1T&gt;` appearing on the Slack channel. Without escaping I get a better result without escaping: `FYI <@U830369DK> <@U6M9NQD1T>`. But 
Slack is still not interpreting the user ids properly because these user ids are surrounded by angle brackets, not clickable and not highlighted. The recipients are not told they have a personal message.

Comment: Well, I was basing my answer on the available documentation from Ansible. Apparently, it is not accurate. You can try to use un-escapted brackets and set the property `link_names` to 1. If that does not work either, then I suggest to open and issue at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues